# VSCode Debug Add Configuration error Cannot read property 'openConfigFile' of undefined

Tags: debugging, vs-code, apex-replay-debugger

I created a Salesforce project in VSCode and when I try to debug Apex Classes adding a Debug Configuration I get the following error:
 
`Cannot read property 'openConfigFile' of undefined`
I'm using the Mac version of VSCode and the extensions enabled and the "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home" set in settings.json file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in VSCode as if you create the file launch.json manually it works and then you can Add the Apex Replay Debugger Configuration.

Create the file under your project folder with the name launch.json

Set the file with the following configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [   

    ]
}
```

Save the file and you will see a button "Add Configuration" where you can add the Configuration you need as "Apex Replay Debugger".

Hope it helps!